# Get Index of a Node in NodeView/TreeView

Tags: c#, gtk#

I need to know the row/index of a node within a NodeView on  a mouse click, in order to remove the corresponding value from a list.

I did manage to get the ButtonPressEvent working, but i don't know how to determine to index of the clicked row.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I think you can get the selected nodes from NodeView.NodeSelection.SelectedNodes. Look at this diagram http://sourcecodebrowser.com/gtk-sharp2/2.12.9/class_gtk_1_1_node_view.html.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately i didn't find what i was looking for within the documentation you linked. But i found a Solution non the less. I just added a additional property to my custom TreeNode class, holding its index.